# Как отправить cUrl запрос и получить ответ?

Tags: php, curl

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно отправить GET на https://api.interkassa.com/v1/co-invoice/79008427 с header'ами:

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: Basic lock" "https://api.interkassa.com/v1/co-invoice/79008427"
```

и должен прийти ответ в json.

Каким образом отправить этот запрос и получить ответ?

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо сделать GET - запрос (он установлен по умолчанию). Список действий по шагам:

1. Инициализируете новое соединение curl с нужным адресом
2. Задаёте параметры запроса, а именно заголовки и настройку `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` для возврата данных из ответа на запрос в переменную (по умолчанию curl печатает эти данные в стандартный вывод т.е. на экран)
3. Выполняете запрос
4. Проверяете, корректно ли завершился запрос по **error number** (0 - успех)
5. Закрываете соединение curl

   ```
   $ch = curl_init('https://api.interkassa.com/v1/co-invoice/79008427');
   curl_setopt_array($ch, [
       CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['Authorization: Basic lock', 'Accept: application/json'],
       CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
   ]);
   $result = curl_exec();

   If (curl_errno($ch) == 0) {
       $data = json_decode($result, true);
   } else {
       $data = false;
   }

   curl_close($ch);
   ```

Comment: И еще, не уверен что заголовок `Authorization` здесь верный - скорее всего его значение просто `Basic`

Answer (score -1):

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Authorization: Basic lock" "https://api.interkassa.com/v1/co-invoice/79008427'
    ));

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно на свой ответ. На хедеры